# stripe on ios show STPAddCardViewController with address field

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

I'm trying to use the `STPAddCardViewController` in the Stripe library to show the view for adding a card, and configuring it to require address as well. 
This is what I have, which doesn't work and throws an exception:

```
@IBAction func addCardAction(sender: AnyObject)
{

    let paymentConfig = STPPaymentConfiguration.init();
    paymentConfig.requiredBillingAddressFields = STPBillingAddressFields.Full;

    let theme = STPTheme.defaultTheme();

    let addCardViewController = STPAddCardViewController.init(configuration: paymentConfig, theme: theme);
    addCardViewController.delegate = self;

    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: addCardViewController);
    self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil);
}
```

If i just initialize without a config, I see the view come up just fine with the card and email fields (without the address), like so:

```
@IBAction func addCardAction(sender: AnyObject)
{

    let addCardViewController = STPAddCardViewController()
    addCardViewController.delegate = self

    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: addCardViewController)
    self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)        
}
```

Exception I see:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSCFConstantString stringByAppendingString:]: nil argument'

thrown at this line:

```
let addCardViewController = STPAddCardViewController.init(configuration: paymentConfig, theme: theme);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your publishableKey to the paymentConfig, fixed it for me

```
    paymentConfig.publishableKey = "pk_test_xxxxxxxx"
```